# Closures with validation rules for domain object properties

Tags: php, object-oriented

It is nice to be able to set your data in a domain object like so:

```
$order->setId($id);
$order->setCustomer($customer);
$order->setItems($items);
```

And then be able to do

```
if( !$order->validate() ) {
    // Invalid data
}
```

Which will validate all the set data and tell you if it was valid or not. I have an implementation of this I came up with but it is sort of messy and limited to only certain common validation rules like checking the type, length/range and format of the data.

I have been doing a lot of Javascript lately and I like the idea of the anonymous functions and I just found out you can do them in PHP 5.3+ and you can use the `$this` keyword from PHP 5.4.

```
abstract class AbstractEntity {

    private $id = 0;
    private $validations = array();

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;

        // A function to validate the Id
        $this->addValidation( function() {
            return ( $this->id > 0 );
        });
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function validate() {
        foreach($this->validations as $validation) {
            if( $validation() === false ) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected function addValidation($function) {
        $this->validations[] = $function;
    }

}
```

The `Order` class:

```
class Order extends AbstractEntity {

    private $customer;
    private $items = array();
    private $status;

    public function setCustomer(Customer $customer) {
        $this->customer = $customer;

        // Make sure the customers account is active
        $this->addValidation( function() {
            return ( $this->customer->isActive() );
        });
        // Do as many complex validations as needed
    }

    public function setStatus($status) {
        $this->status = $status;

        // The status has to be 'Pending' or 'Complete'.
        $this->addValidation( function() {
            return ( ($this->status === 'Pending') || ($this->status === 'Complete') );
        });

}
```

Doing it this way validations of all different levels of complexity can be done. I was thinking of adding in another parameter to the `addValidation()` method so you can group validation rules together so they execute in a certain order.

It needs extra functionality like setting error messages but that should not be too hard to implement.

I was also thinking of maybe making the `addValidation()` method public so you can add validations outside of the class that will execute when the `validate()` method is called. This could be handy in some scenarios.

Is this a good or bad idea? I would like to see some opinions before I go and change all my code to using this sort of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

my two cents :

- I think tying validation activation to setters is not really good. What if you never set any value on your object ? It will be considered valid ! And what happens if you set the property more than once ?
- Some implementations use external validator objects, which allow more flexibility (validation rules often vary, according to which user requests saving for instance). When you call `validate()`, you either pass a validator instance or let the object use a default validator. As a side note, coming from Rails / ActiveRecord, I can tell that complex projects often do not turn well when your domain object's lifecycle is so tightly tied to a single validation scheme !
- Speaking DDD lingo, some of your problems might be efficiently solved using [Value objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object). For instance, your `Id` property could be a value object that has a `isValid()` method (it would be responsible for its own validation). Wether or not this is a good idea depends on your domain.